# HTML layout different tables with same columns and td percent width

Tags: html, html-table

I have a problem with laying out tables on an HTML page. I have one div container with several tables one below the other. All tables always have 100% as width. In all tables the tds have the same column width, e.g.

```
Table 1   
Col 1: width 15%|Col 2: width 20%|Col 3: width 35%|Col 4: width 30%

Table 2   
Col 1: width 15%|Col 2: width 20%|Col 3: width 35%|Col 4: width 30% 

...    
Table n
```

If I use the Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome everything looks good, but if I use the IE or the Edge the problem occurs and is getting worse if I resize.

I don't understand what the problem could be. I expected that the columns are always equal between the different tables because of the percentages.

I created a snippet from the code (it's very old and from another person, so please excuse if it's not good.):

https://jsfiddle.net/uag2Ldur/#&togetherjs=3VaeO1f97c

I recognized that the content is too wide for the cell but what can I do so that it looks/behave the same in the IE like in Firefox?

Comment: please show codes use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: please post the code you have already worked on (preferably in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) so you can get help faster.

Comment: At the moment I cant post my code because its too long and contains data I'm not allowed to show, I will try to reduce my code.

Comment: I posted code above

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the different sizes across browsers could be, in part, due to the default amount of margin and padding that each browser applies to the different HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may use this to fix it

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">input</th>
    <th colspan="2">input</th> 
    <th colspan="2">Input</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
th, td {

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

in the css for your tables?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

EDIT:

Ok, my first thought on your fiddle way "crikey, I haven't seen font tags for a long time".  :)

My second was that although you can specify widths on columns, html tables like to do their best to accomodate the content regardless.

I have produced an updated fiddle from your sample using css rather than all those attributes so it's cleaner and easier to read.  The main thing though that fixes the layout in IE is the table-layout:fixed that I suggested earlier.  If you take that out you see the tables misaligned in IE and Edge.

https://jsfiddle.net/6um81q3b/1/

I've tested this sample in Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge.

Comment: I already tried this but then I got other problems. I will try again and let you know what the new problems are.

Comment: I tried it and for the code that I posted above, it would be a solution. But I had another code where there were other problems. I try to post this code, too.

Comment: I have a code where there are other problems: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jqwth02m/#&togetherjs=OcnJEUj79x). In the second colum there are two columns that have a width of 11%, but these columns have different widths, now. They should be equal. How could this be?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you effort! It looks really different, now. It would take me a lot of time to change my second code like this, so maybe you can already say if your version would solve my problem (that two columns with 11% have different widths in the table)? Then I will try it.